# OpenDS control panel login password issue

Tags: opends

I am unable to login to Open DS from front end using my credentials.

`Bind DN: cn = Directory Manager Passowrd: xxxxxx`

Error message shown is:

```
Check that Administrative User DN or Password is valid
```

When i am using the same through my code i am facing no issues.
How to change password and check?

Answer (score 0):

OpenDS is no longer maintained by the project owner, and I wouldn't be surprised if your problem is due to new versions of Java. I suggest that you look at OpenDJ, the actively developed and open source fork of OpenDS. opendj.org